# Is there anyway to specifically target numbers within text in css?

Tags: html, css

So as explained in the title, I have a contents table in my page that is dynamically created along with numbers. Note that I have not used css numbering. The contents table/list is created the usual way dynamically with ol and li. But based on a specific data attribute I would like to hide or show these numbers in the list. Is there anyway to target them to display as none? So like to target int within?

```
function drawOlForItems(itemsToDraw, parentIndex) {
        var $ol = $("<ol>");

        itemsToDraw.foreach(function (item, index) {
            var entryIndex = index + 1;
            var $li = $("<li class='toc-level-{0}'>".format(item.level));
            var itemIndex = parentIndex != null ? "{0}.{1}".format(parentIndex, entryIndex) : entryIndex;
            $li.append("<span class='entry-text'>{0}) {1}</span>".format(itemIndex, item.heading));
            //$li.append("{0}".format(item.heading));

            if (item.subItems.length) {
                var subItems = drawOlForItems(item.subItems, itemIndex);
                $li.append(subItems);
            }
            $ol.append($li);
        });

        return $ol;
    }
```

EDIT: Is it possible to select specific unicode characters? As in, is there a way to select the number 1 for example specifically?

This is the html div where the list is being injected into:

```
<div id="inject-toc-here" style="font-family:'Century Gothic'" data-show-numbers="" data-cssNumbering="">

</div>
```

EDIT 2: To clarify I want to hide the numbering, not the elements of the list, just the numbers alongside them. I am not using css numbering.

Comment: show your code and explain exactly what you want

Comment: Try `list-style-type: none;` for `<ul>`

Comment: That does not work because it hides the whole table @Chaska

Comment: Then you should assign a class for those `<li>` with specific data attribute and set like this:  `li.special { list-style-type: none; }` or `li[data-attr="special"] { list-style-type: none; }`

Comment: @Chaska the problem is that the data-attribute is applied to the whole div because the items are dynamically injected.

Comment: Can you show your HTML output? and which element you are looking to hide?

Comment: @caiovisk Edited

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the attribute selectors in CSS to change styles according to the data:

```
div[data-show-numbers="no"] li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```css
div[data-show-numbers="no"] li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
data-show-numbers="no"
<div id="inject-toc-here" style="font-family:'Century Gothic'" data-show-numbers="no" data-cssNumbering="">
  <ol>
    <li>Listing numbered</li>
    <li>Listing numbered</li>
    <li>Listing numbered</li>
    <li>Listing numbered</li>
    <li>Listing numbered</li>
    <li>Listing numbered</li>
    <li>Listing numbered</li>
    <li>Listing numbered</li>
  </ol>
</div>

data-show-numbers="yes"

<div id="inject-toc-here" style="font-family:'Century Gothic'" data-show-numbers="yes" data-cssNumbering="">
  <ol>
    <li>Listing numbered</li>
    <li>Listing numbered</li>
    <li>Listing numbered</li>
    <li>Listing numbered</li>
    <li>Listing numbered</li>
    <li>Listing numbered</li>
    <li>Listing numbered</li>
    <li>Listing numbered</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

You can also have a look on `:nth-child` Pseudo-class if you are looking to apply the styles for matching elements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: Yeah unfortunately this will select the whole table as the data-attribute sits in the div that the table is injected into. I tried the nth-child selector and this selected whole rows in the table because the numbers and text of the row are 1 child.

Comment: By which data attribute you're wanting to hide?

Comment: It's not the attribute I want to hide, it is the numbering based on what te attribute is equal to.

Comment: I could not understand properly what you want. Are you want to hide the the list style (numbers in case of the `ol`) of some elements inside your div based on data attribute? could you explain better?

Comment: Your edited answer is a lot closer to what I want, thank you, I will give it a try.